# When can we have $AA \subseteq A$ but not $A\le G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $A$ a non empty subset of $G$. We define $AB$ as follows:
$$AB = \{ab: a\in A, b\in B\} $$

It is clear that $A\le G$ implies $AA \subseteq A$ from the closure of the groups operation, but it is claimed on my textbook that the reverse is false. I tried but I couldn't find any counterexamples. It seems to me that if $AA \subseteq A$ and if it weren't a group, by multipllying $A$ by itself enough times you would get something that's not in $A$, but by definition it's not possible.

When can we have $AA \subseteq A$ but not $A\le G$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $G$ be the group of integers with the operation of addition.
Take the set $A=\{a\in G\mid a\geq 2\}$.
Then $A+A\subseteq A$ but $A$ is not a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Thank you, didn't even consider infinite groups. Now I'm curious, is there a finite counter example?

Comment: Why $a \ge 2$ in particular? $a \ge 0$ will work.

Comment: No there is no finite counterexamples, because $g^{-1}$ is equal to a positive power of $g$ for $g \in G$ when $G$ is finite.

Comment: Indeed, other restrictions on $a$ will work.